# Does grep on AIX support the?

Tags: grep, aix

I am trying to use the following grep command

```
grep "Fred\(eric\)\? Smith" names.txt
```

where names.txt contains Fred Smith and Frederic Smith. However, grep only matches Frederic Smith. So, is ? supported in grep where ? refers to the character occurring 0 or 1 time.

Answer (score 1):

AIX uses UNIX grep. So it [supports basic RE](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep). But I suggest you use [extended RE](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) with `-E` option. Then you dont have escape those special characters.

```
grep -E "Fred(eric)? Smith" names.txt
```